# How to print values in Matlab using if statement

Tags: matlab

please help me so this is may program:

```
a= 3;
for i = 1-5
   for j = -2-5
       d = a + i +j;
       fprintf(' %d, %d, %d,\n',a,b,d);
    end
end
```

there no values display in excel, please help me out thanks

Comment: Strangely, now a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239266/how-to-display-string-in-table-using-matlab

Answer (score 2):

Proper indentation would really help here. Each `if` statement must have an associated `end` ***before*** the next statement. Yours are all at the end. This should work better:

```
fileID = fopen('PROBSET_3.csv','w');
a= 3;
lamda = 1.54;

fprintf(fileID, ' h, k, l ,d, theta \n');
for h = -8:8
   for k = -8:8
      for l = -8:8
         d = sqrt((a^2)/(h^2 + k^2 + l^2));
         c = (lamda/(2*d));
         if c<=1
            fprintf ('theta = asind(c)');
         end   %// end moved here
         if c>1
            fprintf ('theta =out of range');
         end   %// end moved here
         fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n',h,k,l,d,theta);
      end
   end
end

fclose(fileID);
```

As an alternative to using two `if` statements, in this case you could use an `else` instead of the second `if`:

```
         if c<=1
            fprintf ('theta = asind(c)');
         else   %// else c > 1
            fprintf ('theta =out of range');
         end
```

Comment: i want the "out of range" be display or print to the table

Comment: also the combination of h k l are not displayed

Comment: @nobel Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. Since you don't use the file handle, the messages should print to the screen. If you want them to be printed to the file you'll have to add `fileID` as the first parameter.

Comment: i want it to be display at excel file, at combination of -8 - 8 -8 the theta should be 'out of range'

Comment: @nobel Then change the messages to `fprintf (fileID, 'theta = whatever...`. You might also want to add a linefeed at the end of each message, but I don't have an example of your desired output. Other than the fact that you don't give `theta` a value, I can't see anything else obviously wrong.

Comment: @nobel If this is not what you want, please edit your question to include the current output and desired output of your code so that everybody is clear what we're trying to do.

Comment: i tried your code and it gives an error: Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs. Error in me (line 17)
         fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d,
         %d\n',h,k,l,d,theta);

Comment: @nobel The only place I see `theta` referenced is in the `fprintf` statement. Perhaps you meant to assign `theta` before the `fprintf`?