# How to display string in table using matlab

Tags: string, matlab

This is my program code:

```
fileID = fopen('PROBSET_102.csv','w');
a= 3;
lamda = 1.54;

fprintf(fileID, ' h, k, l ,d, theta \n');
for h = -8:8
   for k = -8:8
       for l = -8:8
           d = sqrt((a^2)/(h^2 + k^2 + l^2));
           c = (lamda/(2*d));
           if c>1
               theta = ('out of range');
           else 
               theta = asind(c);

           end
            fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n',h,k,l,d,theta);
       end
   end
end


fclose(fileID);
```

I am trying to print the following values on a table: h, k,l,d,theta. But when c value is greater than 1, the theta column should display 'out of range' instead of the actual number output. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution closest to your original code:

As the other suggested, your code error because you are sending data of different type to the `fprintf`. You can either specify a different `format` for `fprintf` and call it with this specific format in the conditional part of you code (the other 2 solutions show you how to do that).

If you want to keep your `fprintf` call outside of the conditional branch, just make sure your parameter `theta` is always the same type (a `string` in this case).

*Since the final result will be to convert numbers to string in the file anyway, we can do it early for this variable and make sure `fprintf` always receive the same type.*

```
if c>1
   theta = 'out of range' ;             %// this is a string
else 
   theta = sprintf( '%d' , asind(c) ) ; %// this is also a string
end
fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %s\n',h,k,l,d,theta); %// last parameter printed is a string
```

---

### Alternatively:

If you are flexible on the text which should be displayed for the "*out of range*" values (that is if you can accept to have "NaN" instead), then `NaN` (it stands for **N**ot **A** **N**umber, but it's not important here) is  a valid *numeric* double precision value which can be handled seamlessly by `fprintf` (*and family of*) function.

It means that you could get rid of you triple nested `for` loop and vectorize your full code. On my machine it execute about 10x faster (calculations + file writing) but your mileage may vary. If you plan on enlarging the grid size, the gain in speed will be even more interesting, although there will be a size where the memory will be your limiting factor.

The vectorized code is as follow:

```
a= 3;
lamda = 1.54;

gridBase = -8:8 ; %// create a vector [-8 -7 -6 .... 6 7 8]

[L,K,H] = ndgrid(gridBase,gridBase,gridBase) ;  %// Generate a grid
D = sqrt( (a.^2) ./ (H.^2 + K.^2 + L.^2) );     %// calculate D in one block (over the full grid)
C = lamda ./ (2.*D);                            %// same for C
C(C>1) = NaN ;                                  %// make values of C>1 stand out (assign then to "Not a Number" NaN)
A = [H(:) K(:) L(:) D(:) C(:)] ;                %// collate all that in a big table (equivalent to what you'll have in your file)

%// now write the array into file
fileID = fopen('PROBSET_102_alternate.csv','w');
fprintf(fileID, ' h, k, l ,d, theta \n');       %// write header line
fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n' , A.'); %'// let Matlab manage the write loop in the background (much faster)
fclose( fileID);
```

---

If you need to understand the code, I invite you to run the above line by line (starting with a small grid size first) and look at the variables in the workspace explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift your `fprintf` calls into your logic for `c`. With the above format string, your `fprintf` call is trying to print `theta` as a double when it's a string.

Does this give you what you're expecting?

```
fileID = fopen('PROBSET_102.csv','w');
a= 3;
lamda = 1.54;

fprintf(fileID, ' h, k, l ,d, theta \n');
for h = -8:8
   for k = -8:8
       for l = -8:8
           d = sqrt((a^2)/(h^2 + k^2 + l^2));
           c = (lamda/(2*d));
           if c>1
               theta = ('out of range');
               fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %s\n',h,k,l,d,theta);
           else 
               theta = asind(c);
               fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n',h,k,l,d,theta);
           end
       end
   end
end

fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: trying that code gives this error: Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in tr (line 5)
fprintf(fileID, ' h, k, l ,d, theta \n');

Comment: I didn't change that line from the code you provided. You likely don't have write access to your current MATLAB directory.

Comment: you're genius!! great syntax! :)

Answer (score 0):

With the `%d` FormatSpec in `fprintf` you can only export intergers, and not strings of characters.

You have to modify the FormatSpec in `fprintf` inside your condition:

```
% ...

if c>1
    theta = ('out of range');
    fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %s\n',h,k,l,d,theta);
else 
    theta = asind(c);
    fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n',h,k,l,d,theta);
end

% ...
```

or simply:

```
% ...

if c>1
    fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, out of range\n',h,k,l,d);
else 
    theta = asind(c);
    fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n',h,k,l,d,theta);
end

% ...
```